# Deriving this Maclaurin expansion approximation of an even function at the origin $r=0$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, approximation

For an even function $f(r)$ that is non-zero at $r=0$ and symmetric around $r=0$, i.e. $f(r)=f(-r)$, I want to be able to approximate the expression

$$
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \Bigg\vert_{r=0}. \tag{1}
$$

However, since I want the approximation at $r=0$, the problem is that the $1/r$ factor makes it diverge. (The purpose of wanting to do this is ultimately to numerically solve a PDE in radial coordinates using finite differences).

I have seen several times (see for example Eq. 12 of [this paper](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/Journal-of-Biomedical-Optics/volume-11/issue-3/034031/Temperature-distribution-in-selective-laser-tissue-interaction/10.1117/1.2204615.pdf) or p. 360 of [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/imamat/article-pdf/20/3/355/1851234/20-3-355.pdf?casa_token=sQK6vgC2dBQAAAAA:H3uywwyD4BZMEWJgde8Qh3Je5T1vK840-VPRvK1hPJcVQn-RXriIwADQyAKewpNtemhoEa2unRH2)) that the following approximation should hold at the origin, in order to get around the singularity problem
$$
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\Bigg\vert_{r=0}\approx \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}\Bigg\vert_{r=0},  \tag{2}
$$
and I would like to see where it comes from.

If I try to derive this approximation by Maclaurin expansion in some small $\delta r$ about the point $r=0$, I get the following up to second order:
$$
f(\delta r) \approx f(0) + \delta r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}  \Bigg\vert_{r=0} + \frac{1}{2} \delta r^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}  \Bigg\vert_{r=0} + \,\,\,\,...   \tag{3}
$$
Rearranging, this becomes
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}  \Bigg\vert_{r=0} &\approx \frac{2}{\delta r^2}\Bigg( f(\delta r) -  f(0) - \delta r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}  \Bigg\vert_{r=0} \Bigg)  \tag{4}\\
&= \frac{2}{\delta r}\Bigg( \frac{f(\delta r) -  f(0)}{\delta r} -  \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}  \Bigg\vert_{r=0} \Bigg) \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Now I know that the first derivative is defined as
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\Bigg\vert_{r=0}  = \lim_{\delta r\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\delta r)-f(0)}{\delta r}  \tag{6}
$$
so for small $\delta r$ the equation should become
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}  \Bigg\vert_{r=0} &= \frac{2}{\delta r}\Bigg( \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\Bigg\vert_{r=0}-  \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}  \Bigg\vert_{r=0} \Bigg)  \tag{7}\\
&= 0,
\end{align}
$$
which is not the same as the approximation given in Eq. (2). Where have I gone wrong here? How can I arrive successfully at Eq. (2)?

Thanks!

Comment: References to charged articles are nonsensical.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Apologies, I think I have now corrected the links to be direct pdfs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust All I can say about $f$ is that it is an even function that is non-zero at $r=0$.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I misread the approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of an even function is odd and is zero at the origin.

By Taylor on $f'$,

$$f'(r)=rf''(0)+o(r)$$

and

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{f'(r)}r=f''(0).$$

---

Notice that approximation is understood as

$$\left.\left(\frac1r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)\right|_{r=0}$$ and not

$$\frac1r\left.\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right|_{r=0}\right).$$